# How to get paper size from printer variable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

I have 3 printers connected to my PC and on my win form I select the print by name, in code, (I don't use PrintDialog). Every printer has different paper size (small, medium and large). Is any way I can get the paper size for current printer.
I try

```
Console.WriteLine(e.PageSettings.Bounds.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(e.PageSettings.PaperSize.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(e.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(e.Graphics.ClipBounds.ToString());
```

I get the variable e from my delegate parameter method:

```
// When I launch my printer (in class constructor):
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintLabel);
//.... other code



//My delegate method:
   private void PrintLabel(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
   {
      //This is my code from above:
        Console.WriteLine(e.PageSettings.Bounds.ToString());
      // other code
   }
```

But it show me the same size no matter which printer I use.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should include how you get the variable `e`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't just use *specialy designed classes* from `System.Drawing.Printing` namespace?
Or I've missed something in the question?

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;

public static PageSettings GetPrinterPageInfo(String printerName) {
  PrinterSettings settings;

  // If printer name is not set, look for default printer
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(printerName)) {
    foreach (var printer in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters) {
      settings = new PrinterSettings();

      settings.PrinterName = printer.ToString();

      if (settings.IsDefaultPrinter)
        return settings.DefaultPageSettings;
    }

    return null; // <- No default printer  
  }

  // printer by its name 
  settings = new PrinterSettings();

  settings.PrinterName = printerName;

  return settings.DefaultPageSettings;
}

// Default printer default page info
public static PageSettings GetPrinterPageInfo() {
  return GetPrinterPageInfo(null);
}

...

// Default printer default page
PageSettings page = GetPrinterPageInfo(); 
// Or default page of some other printer given by its name
// PageSettings page = GetPrinterPageInfo(MyPrinterName); 

RectangleF area = page.PrintableArea;
Rectangle bounds = page.Bounds;
Margins margins = page.Margins;
```

Comment: You forgot to pass in the printerName in `PageSettings page = GetPrinterPageInfo();`, and to use it inside the method.

Comment: @ANeves: I've used the overloaded version: GetPrinterPageInfo() {return GetPrinterPageInfo(null);} for default printer

Comment: I just try it by adding it to my class constructor PageSettings page = GetPrinterPageInfo(printerName); and it still show the same data no matter which printer name I pass as a parameter. Just to let you know none of this 3 printers is my default one.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yes, sorry, that's true. But you still don't use the `printerName` parameter inside the method. It probably always returns the default printer, or something similar.

Comment: I've tested my code: in "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices and Printers" I've changed "Printing preferences" for my printers (I've got 2 network ones) have set A4 paper size for one printer and A5 for another. And so my code returned different results for the printers.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko there are network printers and network setting are set up correctly (I see different sizes) but your code doesn't pick it up. However when I change the sizes in control panel on my local host it works correctly, do you know why is it like that?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: If the profiles are defined, is it possible to get the selected settings from PrintDialog? not the default settings

Comment: @huMpty duMpty: could you, please, convert your comment into a *question* with examples? Selected settings may vary from printer to printer; I doubt that you (with 10K reputation) are looking for `PrintDialog.PrinterSettings` (every complex problem has an evident but incorrect answer)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: Yes, I have made [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178368/print-file-with-selected-printer-profile-page-size?noredirect=1#comment75371154_44178368) little while ago.