# How to get a printer's paper sources using WMI?

Tags: c#, wmi

`PrinterSettings` has a `PaperSources` property which is a collection of paper sources (trays) available for the printer.

However, I need to get the paper sources using `WMI` but all I see are properties such as 'PaperSizesSupported' and 'PaperTypesAvailable'.

Where are the paper sources property in WMI?

Comment: Why does it have to be WMI?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Because I'm already using WMI to get other properties.

Comment: *[shrug]*  That's not exactly a compelling reason, but OK.  My Google searches suggest that you look at the spooler for this information, not the printer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey How would I get them using PrinterSettings?

Comment: Didn't you just say you already knew how to do that?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No. I know that there's the property and that you need a `PrintDocument` for it and that will get the sources of the current printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no WMI class included the OS that gives the information you are looking for.  In .NET the `PrinterSettings` class this information is gathered through pinvoke calls to the `DeviceCapabilities()` function in `winspool.drv`.  They did not provide those capabilities in any of the `ROOT\cimv2` WMI classes including the following:

- CIM_Printer (This is what Win32_Printer is derived from)
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_Spooler_PrintQueue
- Win32_PerfRawData_Spooler_PrintQueue
- Win32_Printer
- Win32_PrinterConfiguration
- Win32_PrinterDriver
- Win32_PrintJob
- MSFT_Printer (Located in the ROOT/StandardCimv2 namespace with a few other classes)

There are some other printer classes but these are printer classes that include any data used for querying.  If you are developing your solution in .NET I would suggest just using the PrinterSettings class in the System.Drawing namespace ([there is an answer here with a great example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542374/how-to-get-paper-size-from-printer-variable)).  If you are using a scripting language you can accomplish similar work by using the .NET assembly in PowerShell like this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$PrinterSettings = New-Object System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings

ForEach ($Printer in Get-Printer) {

    $PrinterSettings.PrinterName = $Printer.Name
    Write-Host $Printer.Name
    Write-Host $PrinterSettings.PaperSources

}
```